# Reverse an array in Knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

I'm learning how to use Knockout.js.  I want to show the observableArray content reversed, so I use the Knockout reverse function this way:

```
   <ul  data-bind="foreach: anObservableArray.reverse()" >...</ul>
```

But, it doesn't work and no errors occurs. When I try this:

```
<ul  data-bind="foreach: anObservableArray.slice(0).reverse()" >...</ul>
```

It works as expected.  My question is why should I have to copy the entire array when the  reverse function already returns an reversed array?.

Comment: This is one of those rare cases where the question has the actual answer/code i'm looking for thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Calling `reverse` will actually reverse the array in-place (and return it), so you could be running into an issue where it is getting reversed multiple times.

For example, if you had two blocks like:

```
<ul  data-bind="foreach: anObservableArray.reverse()" >...</ul>
<ul  data-bind="foreach: anObservableArray.reverse()" >...</ul>
```

The first would be reversed and the second would be back to the original order.

Better to reverse the copy, especially if you will be adding and removing items from the array.

Comment: I initiated the array with two elements and calling "foreach: ObservableArray.reverse()", effectively reversed the array, but the elements I tried to add after, they didn't appear in the screen, so that means that I can't add a element and then reverse the array, because It supposes that first It adds the element and then  the binding updates the html, Is that right?

Comment: I tried and it dint work, <div data-bind=" foreach: ActivityLogO, reverse: true" class=" overflow-scroll height160"> and also tried the above thing as well.. still it shows me in the ascending order

Comment: @RameshSangili - are you doing `foreach: ActivityLogO.slice(0).reverse()`?

Comment: can't we just get an option for `foreach` that displays in reverse order. surely this is very common and reversing is wasteful (although I realize probably negligible in time)

Answer (score 5):

I got this from my search on this question;reason why it is now necessary to copy the array,

"There was a change in knockout.js 2.2 to make array mutation functions not create a dependency on the observable array. Generally if you want a computed to return a reversed version of the array you will not use reverse on the original array but on a copy. Instead of 
       `self.anObservableArray.reverse()`,
do 
      `self.anObservableArray.slice(0).reverse()`
Example: `http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/3QHM7/1/`

So basically, it is to avoid creating dependency on the observable array.

Answer (score 1):

Because reverse() take effects on the source array instead of return a copy array and knockout call it two times with 'foreach' binding so you will get the same array at the final result.

You can test with this code:

```
<ul  data-bind="foreach: alert(anObservableArray.reverse())" >...</ul>
```